# SQL - How to check for multiple values of one column while only returning one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Sorry if the question was worded weird.

I'm writing a report and I have a table that has fields like this....

```
      applicationID statusid statuscreationdate

      123                  1  3-18-2013
      123                  2  3-27-2013
      124                  1  3-29-2013
      125                  1  4-1-2013
      125                  2  4-3-2013
```

And I only want to return rows with a statusid of 1 BUT I also want to check if a statusid of 2 exists for each applicationid. So the desired query on the above table would produce:

```
     123 3-18-2013
     125 4-1-2013
```

Any help would be appreciated. If more information is needed, let me know. I wanted to keep this as short and simple as possible while including the necessary amount of information.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: corrected the desired results part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 Select * From TableName t
 Where statusID = 1
    And Exists(Select * From tablename
               Where applicationID = t.applicationID 
                  And statusID = 2)
```

Answer (score 9):

This problem is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  applicationID, MAX(statuscreationdate) date
FROM    TableName
WHERE   statusID IN (1, 2)             -- list of statusID 
GROUP   BY applicationID 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT statusID) = 2   -- no of statusID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f885/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)